# How do I add an indeterminate ProgressBar that spins in opposite directions like in some of the newer Android Apps?

Tags: android

I have noticed lately that there is a new style of indeterminate progress bar, it looks almost the same except there are two circles sniping in opposite directions.

Is this something the developers created or does it come with the SDK? I am building with 4.2.2 but I still get the old progress bar with only one spinning circle.

Answer (score 1):

it comes with the SDK but your phone will display it's own default progressbar instead of the android holo one if one exists.

To make sure you always use the android holo progressbar, it is recommended that you pull it out of the resources folder and set it manually.

search for progress_large/progress_medium/progress_small.xml in

```
 <sdk folder>/platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable
```

and be sure to copy the related png files too